# How to delete the redundante in an SQL request

Tags: sql

I have an `SQL request`:

```
select "Customer" from "foundry_sync"."data1"
```

The `Customer` is redundant in my table. So the result of my request give me all the list available in the table, as she is.
Which constraint can I add it in my request to recovre the customer without redundante ? I want just recovre the list of my customer.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean, redundant?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using a Queries SQL on PalantirCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Distinct :

```
select Distinct "Customer" from "foundry_sync"."data1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, That's what I'm looking, it worked well.